# How to enable automatic type deduction for class specific typedefs (c++17)?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I would like to deduce a class' (with default template parameter) typedef with c++17 automatically. Does somebody know if this is possible? The following code tries to illustrate this:

```cpp
#include <vector>
template <typename T = int>
struct A{
    using Vec = std::vector<T>;
};

int main() {
    A a{}; // works with c++ 17
    A<int>::Vec vec2{}; //works
    A::Vec vec{}; //does not seem to work with c++ 17. Is that possible somehow?
}
```

In the code above, `a` is instantiated without problems, and the deduced template type is `int` as per default. Nevertheless, I have to pass the parameter type to use the typedef `Vec`. I would be very grateful if somebody knew an answer to the two following questions:

- What is the paper number/title of the ISO mailing list for the feature allowing automatic type deduction for `A a{}`? I am curious to learn more about this feature.
- Is it possible to infer the type of `Vec` automatically without specifying the template type of `A` explicitly?

I am grateful for any hints or suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to infer the type of Vec automatically without specifying the template type of A explicitly?

Yes. You can leave the `<>` empty:

```
A<>::Vec vec{};
```

Otherwise, `A` without `<>` or `<int>` etc., names a template with an unknown template type parameter, and you cannot use that to access nested identifier.

> What is the paper number/title of the ISO mailing list for the feature allowing automatic type deduction for A a{}? I am curious to learn more about this feature.

[P1814](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1814r0.html) is the main paper on class template argument deduction ("CTAD"). [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) is the page on cpprefernece. Note that `A<>::Vec vec{}` does *not* rely on CTAD, as there is no contstructor involved that performs an actual deduction.

Comment: i think thats what OP wants, but its not deduction or inference, but rather the default `int`

Comment: Thank you, @lubgr . I very much appreciate that you also found the paper number.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to infer the type of Vec automatically without specifying the template type of A explicitly?

Yes:

```
A<>::Vec
```